Adding a Private Attribute to a Subclassed NumPy Array
In the NumPy documentation, it is demonstrated that you can add a custom attribute by subclassing the ndarray:
import numpy as np

class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

arr = np.arange(5)
obj = RealisticInfoArray(arr, info='information')
print(obj.info)

This example works perfectly fine. However, if I want to make the new attribute "private" (i.e., by calling the attribute self._info):
import numpy as np

class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self._info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)

arr = np.arange(5)
obj = RealisticInfoArray(arr, info='information')
print(obj._info)

Then None is printed. Can somebody help me understand why this is and how to fix this so that obj._info is not None and behaves the same as the first example?

You need to assign the private property in the __new__() method as well.
import numpy as np

class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj._info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self._info = getattr(obj, '_info', None)

arr = np.arange(5)
obj = RealisticInfoArray(arr, info='information')
print(obj._info)


It appears as if the self._info = getattr(obj, '_info', None) isn't even necessary? I assumed that this was setting self._info but it doesn't seem to be doing that?

There are multiple ways that a numpy array can be initialized. The __array_finalize__() method is needed for some of them, so you need both.

I can still print(obj._info) without self._info = getattr(obj, '_info', None) be there. This doesn't make sense to me

See this section of the page you linked to.

Ahh, I think I understand now. It sounds like the key point is that when we create "new-from-template" (e.g., from slicing - slice = obj[1:]) then the _info attribute will also be passed along. However, if self._info = getattr(obj, '_info', None) is omitted, then the "new-from-template" will NOT have the _info attribute (i.e., it isn't passed along to the newly created object)!

So, with self._info = getattr(obj, '_info' present, the slice = obj[1:]that is created will also have the attributeslice._info. Otherwise, without setting self._info, slice._info` would result in an error

That's the intent, isn't it? There's no way to specify the _info property explicitly when creating a slice, so it just propagates it.
